# How to preserve custom number formatting after closing a workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have created a custom format `##,##0.0,,, CTRL+J %%` in Excel 2010 to display

10000 as 0.1
100000 as 1.0
1000000 as 10.0
10000000 as 100.0
100000000 as 1,000.0
and so forth.

The problem I am facing is that once I apply this format, save and close the workbook, the next time I open it the format gets changed by multiplying by 10 (100000 is displayed as 10.0).

I don't understand how it is getting changed automatically the next time I open it. However, when I apply other formats they remain unchanged.

Comment: I don't quite understand, could you be more clear? You set a custom format and it doesn't stay after closing and opening the workbook?

Comment: Hi, Yeah when I open it next time it doestnt work.... I type "100000" ,I apply the format, it works well show me result as "1.0" then I save it workbook and close it...then if i open it again it shows me "10.0" and not "1.0"

Comment: @Raystafarian..Hope you understood the issue...

Comment: I do, but I haven't had a chance to figure out what's happening as I don't know this off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  I had to define a custom **Style** and apply the Style to the cells. 
This resolved the problem for me.

Comment: Hi,but does the custom style stay the next time you open the file???